Scipy Optimisation Failing - Why is propensity model failing?
I am trying to optimise the premium charged to customers for profit, whilst targeting an overall conversion/retention rate. However, the optimisation process is currently failing, providing this output when I run 'result':
     fun: -298.2633664479155
     jac: array([-0.82517242, -0.60799408, -0.44937897, -0.82517242, -0.72691727,
       -0.84170532, -0.74860764, -0.18024063, -0.74860764, -0.96907043])
 message: 'Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem'
    nfev: 11
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 6
 success: False
       x: array([338.39, 409.57, 453.83, 337.21, 377.76, 330.7 , 366.62, 559.69,
       366.95, 156.04])

The jacobian, highlights that for increases in premium retention drops off, which is expected, and in varies by policy which is expected.
The following is the script I used:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as opt

#Data

cost_prices = np.array([293.2 , 371.08, 479.59, 328.2 , 295.23, 273.17, 303.83, 368.09,
        229.72, 208.64])
initial_premiums = ([338.39, 409.57, 453.83, 337.21, 377.76, 330.7 , 366.62, 559.69,
        366.95, 156.04])


#Objective Function

def objective(premiums, cost_prices):
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premiums)
    profit = np.sum((premiums - cost_prices) * propensities)
    return -profit  # Negate since we are minimizing in scipy

#Propensity Model 

Lower = [0, 215,    231.7,  248.4,  265.1,  281.8,  298.5,  315.2,  331.9,  348.6,  365.3,  382,    398.7,  415.4,  432.1,  448.8,  465.5,  482.2,  498.9,  515.6,  532.3,  549,    565.7,  582.4,  599.1,  615.8,  632.5,  649.2,  665.9,  682.6,  699.3,  716,    732.7,  749.4,  766.1,  782.8,  799.5,  816.2,  832.9,  849.6,  866.3,  883,    899.7,  916.4,  933.1,  949.8,  966.5,  983.2,  999.9,  1016.6, 1033.3, 1050]
Upper = [214.999,   231.7,  248.4,  265.1,  281.8,  298.5,  315.2,  331.9,  348.6,  365.3,  382,    398.7,  415.4,  432.1,  448.8,  465.5,  482.2,  498.9,  515.6,  532.3,  549,    565.7,  582.4,  599.1,  615.8,  632.5,  649.2,  665.9,  682.6,  699.3,  716,    732.7,  749.4,  766.1,  782.8,  799.5,  816.2,  832.9,  849.6,  866.3,  883,    899.7,  916.4,  933.1,  949.8,  966.5,  983.2,  999.9,  1016.6, 1033.3, 1050,   1000000]
COMBINED = [0,  -0.07492837,    -0.222324113125,    -0.366118206625,    -0.506502842875,    -0.64346552175, -0.77682655125, -0.906585931125,    -1.03292335375, -1.155851319,   -1.27517763475, -1.39108199325, -1.50357689425, -1.612457645875,    -1.717749248125,    -1.819798585,   -1.91807908025, -2.013117310375,    -2.104553891,   -2.192376322125,    -2.276801796,   -2.357805312375,    -2.4352071795,  -2.509174589125,    -2.579577849375,    -2.646521652,   -2.7098888055,  -2.769834001625,    -2.826369740125,    -2.879291329375,    -2.92881596125, -2.974713943625,    -3.017214968625,    -3.05629403625, -3.0917589545,  -3.123814415375,    -3.15225572675, -3.17731258075, -3.19875528525, -3.216776032625,    -3.231195130375,    -3.24217977075, -3.24977995375, -3.253765987375,    -3.254342563625,    -3.251304990375,    -3.24484545975, -3.234988971875,    -3.2215183345,  -3.204625739625,    -3.1841564955,  -3.17255777875]


elas = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Lower': Lower,
     'Upper': Upper,
     'COMBINED': COMBINED
    })


def propensity_to_renew(premium):
    prop_vec = []
    for prem in premium:
        val = prem
        lp = float(elas.query(' @val >= Lower and @val < Upper')['COMBINED'])
        prop_vec.append(1/(1+np.exp(-(-1.496+lp))))
    return prop_vec



#Target Overall retention Constraint

def retention_constraint(premiums):
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premiums)
    target_retention = 0.07  # Example target retention rate
    return np.mean(propensities) - target_retention

#Define constraints for the optimizer

constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': retention_constraint}]

#Bounds

bounds = [(0.7*premium,1.3*premium) for premium in initial_premiums]


#Perform Optimisation

result = opt.minimize(objective, initial_premiums, args=(cost_prices), bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

optimal_premiums = result.x
optimal_profit = -result.fun

print("Optimal Premiums:", optimal_premiums)
print("Optimal Profit:", optimal_profit)

#Output (Note Optimised Premium is the same as the input initial Premium)

# Optimal Premiums: [338.39 409.57 453.83 337.21 377.76 330.7  366.62 559.69 366.95 156.04]
# Optimal Profit: 298.2633664479155

Note that the part of the issue seems to be related to the propensity model. For example when I use the below model, the issue disappears. My problem is that, when you graph the propensities relative to premium, they are quite similar, and I don't see the reason why the model above won't converge:
def propensity_to_renew(premium):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(0.01 * (premium - 100)))

Here is chart showing the propensity output by premium:

Can someone please give advice? Happy to provide additional detail if needed.
Thanks

Where is propensity_to_renew defined? Provide a [mcve].

Your code does not produce what you claim it produces; it produces the same premium vector but a profit of 20.69.

There's a severe discontinuity in lower/upper/combined where lower == 0. The curve looks like it can be modelled fairly accurately as a quadratic without that ledge. Do you really need the discontinuity there?

Further, shouldn't your target retention be treated as a minimum (inequality)?

Using a step-wise lookup table for a constraint spells doom for a differential optimiser. And really, that lookup table of yours is exactly quadratic, so it shouldn't exist. I demonstrate how to use the equivalent polynomial:
import functools

import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds


def propensity_to_renew(premium: np.ndarray, propensity_poly: Polynomial) -> np.ndarray:
    interpolated = propensity_poly(premium)
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(1.496 - interpolated))


def objective(
    premium: np.ndarray,
    cost_price: np.ndarray,
    propensity_poly: Polynomial,
) -> float:
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premium=premium, propensity_poly=propensity_poly)
    profit = propensities.dot(premium - cost_price)
    return -profit  # Negate since we are minimizing in scipy


def retention_constraint(premium: np.ndarray, propensity_poly: Polynomial) -> float:
    propensities = propensity_to_renew(premium=premium, propensity_poly=propensity_poly)
    return propensities.mean()


def solve(
    cost_price: np.ndarray,
    initial_premium: np.ndarray,
    lower: np.ndarray,
    combined: np.ndarray,
    target_retention: float = 0.07,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, float]:
    propensity = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x=lower, y=combined, deg=2)
    print('Propensity polynomial:')
    print(propensity)

    result = minimize(
        fun=objective,
        x0=initial_premium,
        args=(cost_price, propensity),
        bounds=Bounds(lb=0.7*initial_premium, ub=1.3*initial_premium),
        constraints=NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=functools.partial(retention_constraint, propensity_poly=propensity),
            lb=target_retention, ub=target_retention,
        ),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    optimal_premiums = result.x
    if np.array_equal(optimal_premiums, initial_premium):
        print('Warning: no progress made in optimisation')
    return optimal_premiums, -result.fun


def main() -> None:
    cost_prices = np.array((
        293.2, 371.08, 479.59, 328.2, 295.23, 273.17, 303.83, 368.09,
        229.72, 208.64,
    ))
    initial_premiums = np.array((
        338.39, 409.57, 453.83, 337.21, 377.76, 330.7, 366.62, 559.69,
        366.95, 156.04,
    ))
    lower = np.array((
        215, 231.7, 248.4, 265.1, 281.8, 298.5, 315.2, 331.9, 348.6, 365.3, 382, 398.7, 415.4,
        432.1, 448.8, 465.5, 482.2, 498.9, 515.6, 532.3, 549, 565.7, 582.4, 599.1, 615.8, 632.5,
        649.2, 665.9, 682.6, 699.3, 716, 732.7, 749.4, 766.1, 782.8, 799.5, 816.2, 832.9, 849.6,
        866.3, 883, 899.7, 916.4, 933.1, 949.8, 966.5, 983.2, 999.9, 1016.6, 1033.3, 1050,
    ))
    combined = np.array((
        -0.07492837, -0.222324113125, -0.366118206625, -0.506502842875, -0.64346552175,
        -0.77682655125, -0.906585931125, -1.03292335375, -1.155851319, -1.27517763475,
        -1.39108199325, -1.50357689425, -1.612457645875, -1.717749248125, -1.819798585,
        -1.91807908025, -2.013117310375, -2.104553891, -2.192376322125, -2.276801796,
        -2.357805312375, -2.4352071795, -2.509174589125, -2.579577849375, -2.646521652,
        -2.7098888055, -2.769834001625, -2.826369740125, -2.879291329375, -2.92881596125,
        -2.974713943625, -3.017214968625, -3.05629403625, -3.0917589545, -3.123814415375,
        -3.15225572675, -3.17731258075, -3.19875528525, -3.216776032625, -3.231195130375,
        -3.24217977075, -3.24977995375, -3.253765987375, -3.254342563625, -3.251304990375,
        -3.24484545975, -3.234988971875, -3.2215183345, -3.204625739625, -3.1841564955,
        -3.17255777875,
    ))

    optimal_premiums, optimal_profit = solve(
        cost_price=cost_prices, initial_premium=initial_premiums, lower=lower, combined=combined,
    )

    print('Optimal Premiums:')
    print(optimal_premiums)
    print(f'Optimal Profit: {optimal_profit:.3f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Propensity polynomial:
-2.70963332 - 1.54330834 (-1.51497006 + 0.00239521x) +
1.09074431 (-1.51497006 + 0.00239521x)**2
Optimal Premiums:
[349.38589473 455.51425069 589.979      393.83507471 351.72217588
 325.62544362 362.72798832 449.65969927 275.87308563 202.852     ]
Optimal Profit: 29.703

